# “Wheeze” when talking about laughing

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the most fitting translation of the English “wheeze” when talking about laughing very hard?

*TujaVortaro* shows two words for “wheeze”: “*fajfspiri*” and “*kraĉospiri*”.  The latter seems to be related to animal sounds, like hissing of a cat or a goose.  The former is neither in *PIV* nor in Kondratiev's Esperanto-Russian dictionary.

There is also “*ŝuŝi*”:

> **ŝuŝ/i** (ntr) Brui simile al gaso eliranta sub forta premo el mallarĝa tubo: […]

Does any one of these fit, or is there another, better word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vi povas uzi `sibl/*`. Temas pri Fundamenta radiko, [kies verba signifo estas](http://vortaro.net/#sibli):

> Eligi sonon similan al longedaŭra «s»

Ekzemple:

```
Dum astma krizo personoj ofte sible spiras
```

Aŭ, el la [Internacia Krestomatio](http://i-espero.info/files/elibroj/eo%20-%20kabe%20-%20internacia%20krestomatio.pdf) (per tekstaro.com):

> La blekado pli kaj pli raŭka kaj dolora de l’ uro miksiĝis kun la siblanta spirado de la brusto de l’ grandegulo.